# How can we get complete records of a column from netezza db table.? By default i am getting only 1000 records

Tags: sql, netezza

How can we get complete records of a column from netezza db table.? By default i am getting only 1000 records.

I am not using any limit keyword to minimize the tailor the output.

For instance,
SELECT Account_number from Customers

In output grid i am getting only 1000 records and After downloading the same output the records remains the same.

I Want all the records,  I have checked the Account_Number column contains more than 20k records.

Comment: How are you getting this 20k records number? from select count(*) ?

Comment: Yes. For checking the exact count i am using count(Account_number)

Comment: What client are you using? to my knowledge there is nothing in the engine which would apply a limit on your results without a limit or some other clause

Comment: could you try running with nzsql or nzpy https://pypi.org/project/nzpy/

Comment: I tried changing the default settings. But things remains the same. I don't Want to use any python library to Fetch the data. The application itself should get the results in the output grid, this will resolve my problem. Is thier any settings to be set for changing the output to Fetch the complete records.?

Answer (score 0):

To overcome with such issue, We Shall create a Temporary table and dump your query output in the temp table.

Post table is created then go to
query  >Current query >Query option dialog will appear.
In that check the option 'keep connection open between executions'
This you have to do it everytime you fire the sql query. It is bit irritating. But you have to manage.